# Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:5000/favicon.ico'

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost, content-security-policy

Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:5000/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I have this meta on index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="font-src 'self' data:; img-src 'self' data:; 
    default-src 'self' http://0.0.0.0:5000/">
```

Comment: And you definitely running on port 5000?

Comment: @chev yes const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

Answer (score 0):

Update you the `meta tag` to use the correct scheme/source:

`img-src 'self' http://0.0.0.0:5000`;

[Ref](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp):

The source list in each directive is flexible. You can specify sources by scheme (data:, https:), or ranging in specificity from hostname-only (example.com, which matches any origin on that host: any scheme, any port) to a fully qualified URI (https://example.com:443, which matches only HTTPS, only example.com, and only port 443). Wildcards are accepted, but only as a scheme, a port, or in the leftmost position of the hostname: *://*.example.com:* would match all subdomains of example.com (but not example.com itself), using any scheme, on any port.